# Which Azure products for public users to upload their private data?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm building an iPhone app that collects user's physiology data (e.g., timing of heart beats), which will be about 5-50mb per session. I'd like to allow users to upload these data with their ID and comments to Azure, but I'm not quite sure which products to use. I was looking at Azure Blob storage but it does not have write permission to public. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't comment on any data privacy topics around this and just caution you to look into this, regardless of the technical solution.

To your question: It really depends on what kind of data formats you are talking about. If you want to upload things like images, then yes, Blob storage would be a good fit. You would probably have some back-end service in the cloud, that the app calls and requests a one-time write-access token to a blob storage account. you return that SAS token to the app and the app can then upload data into that blob storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion.  I didn't know what SAS token was, but looks like a good solution.  The data is just a big .csv file with numerical values.  Because later on I also need to perform search operations (e.g., by user ID).  Do you think it is better to use Data Lake to store everything unstructure, or Blob + SQL database, where search is performed and link to filename?

Comment: well, if it is structured data you could of course also directly ingest it into a SQL database. But blob is probably the easier - and cheaper way to start with. Let users upload the data to blob and from there you could for instance have a scheduled job in Azure Data Factory to ingest the new data every few hours into a database.

Comment: or, if you want faster ingest, you could even have a Azure Stream Analytics job running that processes the data from blob the second is finished uploading

Comment: account information is structured, while the data is not.  Currently I don't need fast ingest, so shouldn't be complicated to start.  Thanks so much!